# Access to Oracle Database with sqlapi C++

Tags: c++, sql, oracle

I need to write some data in several database.
I choose sqlapi.com

I have made it for mysql and mssql.
Now I have Problem with Oracle database.

I have installed server and client on Ubuntu.
In browser it works, but sqlapi says:

> libnnz10.so: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory
>
> DBMS API Library 'libclntsh.so'
>   loading fails
>
> This library is a part of DBMS client
>   installation, not SQLAPI++
>
> Make sure DBMS client is installed and
>
> this required library is available for
>   dynamic loading
>
> Linux/Unix:
>
> 1) The directories in the user's
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable
>
> 2) The list of libraries cached in
>   /etc/ld.so.cache
>
> 3) /usr/lib, followed by /lib

There are both of these files depp inside /usr/lib.
I have tried a lot of ways to say eclipse path to this folder, but nothing works.

Thanks for help.

Comment: `libclntsh.so` is the client library to access oracle databases. So basically you're asking how to tell eclipse where to pick up a given DLL right ? I am not sure I understand, do you launch your program from eclipse or from the command line.... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to set the variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the file path of the shared lib.

e.g.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/oracle/instantclient/lib
```

set the variable in .profile or .bash_profile. This depends on the shell you are using.

**Update**

Due to some new security requirements in ubuntu (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/366728 for details) you cannot use LD_LIBRARY_PATH for non-interactive shells. Use the following procedure (adjust the oracle path to your needs):

```
echo "/opt/oracle/product/whatever/lib" | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle.conf
sudo ldconfig -v
```

Comment: yes, probably it has something to do with this path.
"echo LD_LIBRARY_PATH" give me nothing.
i tried change it with this export, resp. 

"export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/client/"

there in subdirectory /lib/ are these *.so files

but doesnt work :-/

Comment: ha! when i add this export to .profile, after restart is variable $LD_LIBRARY_PATH still empty, something rewrites my settings, actually only this variable.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables
"LD_LIBRARY_PATH cannot be set in $HOME/.profile, /etc/profile, nor /etc/environment files. You must use /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf configuration files."

Yes, that was the reason, i found out it yesterday too.
thanks.